# How do I instantiate a generic type/interface in TypeScript which only accepts primitives

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to use a function to create an instance of an interface. This interface has a generic type that should be limited to the primitives `string`, `number` and `boolean`. (`type Primitive = (number | string | boolean);`)

```js
interface MyInterface<T extends Primitive> {
    value: T;
}
```

I am able to create a function signature that produces the expected results, but I am not able to implement it cleanly (without casting the value to any).

I split the problem into three sections to understand it better.

The first two sections are limited to returning the value. The last section is "complete".

The complete code on the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAFAOwFckAjCOKAHygGdhF8BzKqEgezYBsIBDfASgDcAKGEAzQvgDGaNvihS4vYBHjJUGCADkemgDwAVKBAAeK-ABMasRCjSYAfLnQAuKAf5ujAb2FQoSsCEcPLoIgC+otzAUDxQOIrKqrYamDqauABENGxIEADK9AhMmUJQAPTlUKCQUAg0btm5BUUlwnE4mWIcmYIVVQbg0ADkXT3Dddb4bDE8NDQIjPg8JNzVbNVDUKM5eYUMjJnDAHS4AEwAzGdn-MJScnSs8QpKPCpqdprpmLgALDd9SqbWr1Nz-O4PGJSZ6JN7JdT2bS6H70QgQMpAmrQUHVOBo0SiLFQACCMEMxjMEEs1g+qQgDmeRlM5istFazAA-GyDlAvBSWVNiGQKFyiKRyLzWBxuHxAeUmZTqVKuLx5Fz2Cq+JL8BBMHARBD8I9GG5SXo6AcGZ1umxeqIJNJZPJYe8UojycyqazaYinK53J4SWSDAzfP5AsFQnL3FthgYJvUoNNZvNFstVtBgBsicMzSGTn5-EXi-4gf5BrVhj7NAmpjNYqmlis1lngSM8w4CyXu-0SxWRhbioxa0n63MFk2M+s29sOydzlcbsJIlBDY8EDDXq6ERkmnt2aVo0ScYOmGuYgArTdJas-f4YqrHhpJoXkc9QADW17ht4guFR6JHlsOIajK+AEsUKhwGIPBSNAACyIAAJL4FBMFwR6irem6mihoW-joDwnBol4ET2pIMgIHILxJIhKFobBECYQKNg7o4zhESRAZuHRqHkOhTEdnhxYRiEUDeIRxEQOE0b9ts8aTKOKYTumLbZrGc7HPhPY6aWVTlrGv4jsmDYqc2mbqZWmnabpPZlkWcnDKew6KSZ45puZ045ppC7XLctm2ZUxRgIQwDHMANAmLgFwAAwADRQAArIGBgABbQKYkAyBAFgzvceTWGIcC5FAYDFZAcCgNsklohMADuqUIFIqWKRYEBSJwPBKLl6VKFA1E5rxDEYUJwzLqI9xGjEJjfioQ38YxWS7C0ByHr2T48chfHQYx5rsg474gLNEDzTtcF-AC63Ac+p0CXoYrCgdk2PAAXsdt2LQBD4zjiH0YaBqoOEAA)

The naive approach returns the "literal" type. This is not what I want.

```js
type Primitive = (number | string | boolean);

function createPrimitiveNaive<T extends Primitive>(v: T): T {
  return v;
}

let a = createPrimitiveNaive("someString"); // type is: "someString"
a = "foo"; // Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"someString"'.(2322)
const b = createPrimitiveNaive(42); // type is: 42
const c = createPrimitiveNaive(true); // type is: true
```

The advanced approach uses inferred types. This one is based on [the example from the TypeScript documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) The documentation leaves out the implementation. I don't understand why the compiler complains string would not be assignable to AP. Because `const g: AP<string> = "fo";` is not a problem.

```js
type AP<T extends Primitive> = T extends string ? string : T extends number ? number : boolean; //T extends boolean ? boolean : never;

const g: AP<string> = "foo";

function createPrimitive<T extends Primitive>(v: T): AP<T> {
  return v; // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'AP<T>'.
            //   Type 'Primitive' is not assignable to type 'AP<T>'.
            //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AP<T>'.(2322)
}
 
const i = createPrimitive("someString"); // type is: string
const j = createPrimitive(42); // type is: number
const k = createPrimitive(true); // type is: boolean
```

The last part is what I actually want to do.

```js
interface MyInterface<T extends Primitive> {
    value: T;
}

function createMyInterface<T extends Primitive>(value: T): MyInterface<AP<T>> {
    return {value}; // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'AP<T>'.
                    //   Type 'Primitive' is not assignable to type 'AP<T>'.
                    //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AP<T>'.(2322)
                    //input.tsx(30, 5): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'MyInterface<AP<T>>'
}

const x = createMyInterface("someString"); // type is: MyInterface<string>
const y = createMyInterface(42); // type is: MyInterface<number>
const z = createMyInterface(true); // type is: MyInterface<boolean>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, TypeScript does not play well with conditional types as a return type.
Consider using function overloading:

```js
type Primitive = (number | string | boolean);

type AP<T extends Primitive> = T extends string ? string : T extends number ? number : boolean; //T extends boolean ? boolean : never;

function createPrimitive<T extends Primitive>(v: T): AP<T>
function createPrimitive<T extends Primitive>(v: T) {
    return v;
}

const i = createPrimitive("someString"); // type is: string
const j = createPrimitive(42); // type is: number
const k = createPrimitive(true); // type is: boolean
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAFAOwFckAjCOKAHygGdhF8BzKqEgezYBsIBDfASgDcAWABQY0JCgBBGAB4AKlAgAPYBHwATGrEQo0mAHxQcS1eq066DZgH5a9BEygAuKGbUbtUIqXJR7XzIKN3YuXnxBKAB6aI8LbzDuPgDWDmT8Vx8ITDgRcVEAM0J8AGM0NkzSuF51eGRUDAhFZU9LXQaDCENcdDcFfjdZRUMxYrKKqpqeOr1GzBbzLx16-Saevvd%20KABvMQBIGuBCOEz0fIBfMTFSyrooBBMoatqIVfmIXAAiGjYkCAAyo4mF8hDFolBJNAEDQ3NYnIwbndgFAAFZPF4zN5zLq4AAsACYwbFIeBobCfMRgkj8PcANYY6azTpNXD0QgQYkQqEPClJCJAA)

Btw, there are more primitives. `bigint, symbol` are also primitives

Comment: Using an overload skirts around the issue, since the return type is no longer checked for type safety. This is effectively the same as casting `v` to `any` on return.

Comment: Overloading behaves bivariantly. In this case it is much safer than type casting.

Comment: I am aware that there are more primitives. However I am only concerned with those three basic primitives.